# How to dynamically show/hide multiple sliders via jQuery

Tags: jquery

I am running into an issue trying to create and show/hide an array of sliders via a vertical slider of thumbnails. I have set up an example of what I am attempting to do here:

http://testsite.thedevbox.net/

I am loading 4 Revslider generated sliders into individual divs on the right, with a vertical slider of thumbnails on the left. With css all but the initial sliders are hidden, and then I am using the following code to attach the show/hide events on click in the thumbnails:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('#projectsnav li').click(function() {
        jQuery('.slidergroup').hide();
        jQuery("div[data-sliderord='" + jQuery(this).data('sliderord') + "']").show(400);
    });
});
```

I am running into a couple of issues though:

1) The initially loaded slider is fine, but all of the others are coming out way too small. However, if I click away from the page and come back, the active slider looks fine, although all of the others, including the initially loaded one, does not. Things I have tried that did not work include blurring then focusing the window via Javascript after each slider shows, and calling the .revredraw() (included with the Revslider API) method on the appropriate sliders after showing them.

2) For some reason in the vertical slider, the circular elements wind up being invisible when scrolling through the slides, ie. scroll up twice, and the first slide is invisible (but present and clickable) in the bottom slot. We set this up in a non-Wordpress environment and it is happening there as well:

http://testsite.thedevbox.net/tmp/

Comment: try to include as much code in the question or create a sample code-block with the issue.  no one will know what is revredraw()

Comment: @karthick - my bad, edited to specify that .revredraw() is part of the Revslider api.

Comment: But we still don't know what's wrong, since that looks like okay jQuery; without knowing the HTML it's supposed to be running on. Also, that code will likely disappear once you figure it out, which would render this question useless to anyone else.

Comment: @mike-mccaughan is there a way to replicate something like the Revslider framework into a JS Fiddle or some such, including all of the images?